# Raster clipping without producing no data values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, nodata, clip

I'm trying to clip a raster in ArcMap using a polygon, and I'm wondering if there's any way to have the resulting raster **not include any** "no data" values (I apologize for the poor grammar). My process in pictures is as follows:

Input Raster:

[image]

Polygon as clipping extent:

[image]

Clip tool options:

[image]

Resulting raster with No Data shown in red:

[image]

I just want the resulting raster to consist of the cells that have values. Any hints or tips on how to do this?

P.S. I've tried the Extract by Mask tool and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, by definition, rasters are rectangular in extent. The best you can do is convert the NoData cells to a value using a Raster Calculator with the map algebra expression:

```
Con(IsNull("myraster"), 0, "myraster")
```

[ArcGIS Help 10.2: NoData in Raster Datasets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000002v000000)

Answer (score 2):

Your only options are NoData or Data. You can't have nothing. NoData is as close to nothing as you can get with a raster so unless you want to convert it to a vector format you are stuck with NoData or zeros, or any other number.