Clipping a raster layer to a polygons shapefile but nothing is actually clipped
I am using QGIS. I have the following polygons shapefile of the New York City Boroughs at
EPSG:2263 - NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS)

I then have the following raster grid showing a KDE heat map of some variable:

As we can see here, these the polygons surely overlay over the raster:

What I want to do is clip the raster .tif image to the boundaries of the NYC boroughs polygons. In QGIS I used the 'Clip Raster by Mask Layer' tool, using my NYC borough polygons to clip my KDE heat map raster:

The tool runs, but prints out an odd error message: "ERROR 1: TopologyException: side location conflict at 5314.7723035275021 6620.2844257769075. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.":

And looking out the output raster .tif file, absolutely nothing was clipped:

How come the raster clipping by mask layer process did not actually clip anything, and is there a specific parameter in the tool I forgot to check that caused this process to fail?
EDIT:
For more full context on what I am trying to do:
I have this KDE heat map of power outage frequency across NYC:

I want to understand the relationship between frequencies of power outages and the spread of clean energy technologies across the city. I am only interested in data within the boroughs, and so all space outside of the borough polygons are nodata. And so I made a KDE heatmap of the spread of sites with clean energy technologies across NYC using the KDE Heatmap tool in QGIS:

As you can see here, the raster pixels do not fill out the entirety of the borough polygons. My goal is to run a regression against both raster datasets to see if there is a relationship between the clean energy concentration/density raster and the power outage frequency/distribution raster to see across the city whether these technologies have any impact on their being less localized power outages.
To accomplish this, I would think I would need both raster datasets to be mapped to the same extents within the polygons, making sure all involved data is contained within the borough polygons, not including area outside the polygons.
I am using this python code to carry out this regression:
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Load rasters
smart_control_raster_path = "C:/Users/MyName/Downloads/smart_controls_heatmap.tif"
power_outage_raster_path = "C:/Users/MyName/Downloads/NYC_outage_heatmap.tif"

# Read the smart control raster
with rasterio.open(smart_control_raster_path) as src:
    smart_control_data = src.read(1)
    smart_control_meta = src.meta
    smart_control_transform = src.transform

# Read the power outage raster and resample it to match the smart control raster
with rasterio.open(power_outage_raster_path) as src:
    power_outage_data_resampled = src.read(
        1,
        out_shape=(smart_control_data.shape[0], smart_control_data.shape[1]),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear
    )
    power_outage_transform = src.transform

# Flatten and mask NoData values (-999 assumed, adjust as necessary)
nodata_value = -999
valid_mask = (smart_control_data != nodata_value) & (power_outage_data_resampled != nodata_value)

x = smart_control_data[valid_mask].flatten()
y = power_outage_data_resampled[valid_mask].flatten()

# Add constant for intercept
x_with_const = sm.add_constant(x)

# Run linear regression
model = sm.OLS(y, x_with_const).fit()
print(model.summary())

This is my best attempt at how to code this out, but I am not sure if I am missing anything here.
UPDATE:
Information for my NYC polygons layer:
CRS: EPSG:2263 - NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS)
Extent: 913175.3225450008176267,120128.4696787931461586 : 1067382.5565590744372457,272844.4200069795479067
Information for my power input raster:
CRS: EPSG:2263 - NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS)
Extent: 913180.8803100000368431,120141.1906299999973271 : 1067370.8661400000564754,272839.5088199999881908
For reference, here are the regression results from the above python code that show something went wrong:
C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py:1732: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(weights * (model.endog - mean)**2)
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                       inf
Date:                Tue, 10 Dec 2024   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        22:45:35   Log-Likelihood:            -1.8939e+09
No. Observations:            21214343   AIC:                         3.788e+09
Df Residuals:                21214341   BIC:                         3.788e+09
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const      -4.201e+37   7.57e+34   -555.029      0.000   -4.22e+37   -4.19e+37
x1          2.113e+34    8.3e+30   2546.255      0.000    2.11e+34    2.11e+34
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                  2247075.482   Durbin-Watson:                   0.016
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):          2767440.806
Skew:                           0.859   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Kurtosis:                       2.576   Cond. No.                     2.22e+04
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
[2] The condition number is large, 2.22e+04. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.


A raster will be rectangular by necessity, the clipping will enable you to display it as if it was "clipped" by creating no data cells which you can make transparent.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115334/raster-clipping-without-producing-no-data-values and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457169/removing-no-data-from-raster-images.  In the tool you could have set a no data value.

I see, re-tried the Clip Raster by Mask Layer tool and set the nodata value to 0, but got the original raster I had, not filling up the borough polygons. The article you linked to provided an interesting approach, but did not quite me with what I was looking for, since I received an output raster that did not fill out the borough polygons. I updated my post above for more clarity on my issue, with a more full context of my goal.

Since the error message said the geometry is invalid, have you tried fixing the geometries?

Yes, I tried fixing the NYC boroughs polygons with the 'Fix geometries' tool in QGIS, and using that as the mask layer, but this did not change the produced raster.

Please provide the exact QGIS version used and the CRSs and extents of the layers involved.

@AndreaGiudiceandrea I just now included this information in my post under: "UPDATE:"

At the beginning of the question, you wrote that the layers are in CRS EPSG:4326, while in the UPDATE section that they are in CRS EPSG:2263. Moreover, the error message in the processing's log mentions a coordinates pair which is neither in CRS EPSG:4326 and probably nor in CRS: EPSG:2263 (or it is outside the layer's extent). Are you sure you are using the right layers as the algorithm's inputs?
What is the exact QGIS version that you are running?
It would be useful if you shared the input layers.

Are you sure you are not displaying the clipped raster over the original raster?

Sorry for the confusion. I am using QGIS version 3.62.2.

Looking at my code I see that my input rasters for my regression are 'smart_controls_heatmap.tif' at CRS: EPSG:2263 - NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS) and 'NYC_outage_heatmap.tif' at CRS: EPSG:2263 - NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS). As far as I can tell, these are the correct rasters I should be using. I placed the regression results I received from my code which indicate something went wrong up above in my post update for reference. And yes, I looked at all rasters individually. How can I share the input layers here?

Ah, I see. You mentioned the layer in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. This is the NYC boroughs polygons shapefile. I just trying to use this shapefile as a mask layer to clip the extent of 'smart_controls_heatmap.tif' so that it matches the extent of 'NYC_outage_heatmap.tif', with all data contained within the borough polygons, where nodata pixels are 0s. I am just trying to match these rasters up so they can work with the regression code.

You can fix "ERROR 1: TopologyException... with Fix geometries on the vector layer before you clip

Not sure to understand... Do you have an issue with the "Clip Raster by Mask Layer" processing algorithm not actually clipping the rater layer? If yes, what are the CRS and the extent of the layers used as inputs for such processing algorithm?

Yes, the problem is with the 'Clip Raster by Mask Layer' tool and how it is clipping my raster by the polygons. When I ran the tool I set the nodata value to be 0, but this did not give me what I wanted. For this tool, the input raster is: CRS: EPSG:2263 - NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS) and extent: 918660.5982000000076368,125714.7486999999964610 : 1052730.5981999998912215,268124.7486999999964610. The input polygons are: CRS: EPSG:2263 - NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS) and Extent: 913175.3225450008176267,120128.4696787931461586 : 1067382.5565590744372457,272844.4200069795479067

I continue to not understand why you mentioned a layer with CRS:4326 since it is not involved in the problem. Anyway, I suggest you to split the question in two or more question: one for the 'Clip Raster by Mask Layer' issue and the other(s) for the regression calculation. For the 'Clip Raster by Mask Layer' issue I also suggest you to provide the affected layers.
